# Are there notification calls when a Process exits?

Tags: process, daemon, events

I was thinking about making a tool that triggers some kind of callback once a Process exits, particularly in the case where it's daemon/long-running process.  The idea is to listen for that event, send that event to another system which then listens for the same process to be restarted, without the process itself having to use some lib since this is a kind of cross-cutting concern.  I'd prefer not to poll either, which of course I could do with `ps` or something.

Comment: “Another system”? If two computers communicate, then they form one system (see definition of system “a set of things working together as parts of a mechanism or an interconnecting network; a complex whole.”)

Comment: It is better to monitor the service, not a process. A service can stop, but its process may continue.